# Finding additional function values of an odd-periodic function and period 8

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that f(x) is an odd function, and periodic with period 8. If f(3)=2, find f(4)+f(5), and prove that it must always have the same value.

So far I have f(3)= f(-6+8)= 2 but I don;t even know if this is right.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is periodic
$$f(4)=f(4-8)=f(-4)\\f(5)=f(5-8)=f(-3)$$
Since $f$ is odd
$$f(-4)=-f(4)\\f(-3)=-f(3)$$
Now combine these equations,I'll let you do that.